# Add additional attributes to an existing document elasticsearch

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, document, updating

How do I add additional attributes to an existing document in Elasticsearch index.

```
$ curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/1' -d '{
"user" : "kimchy",
"post_date" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
"message" : "trying out Elastic Search"
}'
```

This would create a document in the index. How do I add an attribute to the document?
Suppose

```
"new_attribute":"new_value"
```

which would modify the document as

```
"user" : "kimchy",
"post_date" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
"message" : "trying out Elastic Search"
"new_attribute" :"new_value"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it is possible with the update api.
Check this :

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#_update_part_of_a_document

and scroll down to "add a new field to the document".

Regards

Comment: My bad. Didn't look at the document carefully. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This link is down, new api doc is here: [ES Update API](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html)

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an old post but i think it can be handy

```
POST /twitter/tweet/1/_update
{
  "doc": {
    "new_attribute":""
  }
}
```