# How to create a new field from existing fields during indexing in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a Lambda that receives events from Kinesis and writes the event to ElasticSearch cluster.

| doc id | FirstTimestamp |
| --- | --- |
| d1 | 15974343498 |

Now when we receive another event, I want to update the document in the ElasticSearch to

| doc id | FirstTimestamp | SecondTimestamp | TimeTag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| d1 | 15974343498 | 15974344498 | 1000 |

How can I do this without having to first GET the existing doc from ElasticSearch and then doing a PUT?

I found the update option [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18466773/add-additional-attributes-to-an-existing-document-elasticsearch) using which I can add the field SecondTimestamp, but how can I add the TimeTag field; it requires us to do an operation using the FirstTimestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GET operation won't be necessary.

Depending on how easily you can configure how your writes happen, you could do the following:

1. Store a script which expects the doc-to-be-updated content as `params`:

```
POST _scripts/manage_time_tags
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless", 
    "source": """
      if (ctx._source.FirstTimestamp != null && params.FirstTimestamp != null) {
        ctx._source.SecondTimestamp = params.FirstTimestamp;
        ctx._source.TimeTag = ctx._source.SecondTimestamp - ctx._source.FirstTimestamp;
      }
    """
  }
}
```

2. Instead of directly writing to ES as you were up until now, use the [`upsert`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/docs-update.html#upserts) method of the Update API:

```
POST myindex/_update/1
{
  "upsert": {
    "id": 1,
    "FirstTimestamp": 15974343498
  },
  "script": {
    "id": "manage_time_tags",
    "params": {
      "id": 1,
      "FirstTimestamp": 15974343498
    }
  }
}
```

This will ensure that if the document does not exist yet, the contents of `upsert` are synced and the script doesn't even run.

3. As new events come in, simply call `/_update/your_id` again but with **the most recent contents** of `id` and `FirstTimestamp`.

```
POST myindex/_update/1
{
  "upsert": {
    "id": 1,
    "FirstTimestamp": 15974344498         
  },
  "script": {
    "id": "manage_time_tags",
    "params": {
      "id": 1,
      "FirstTimestamp": 15974344498
    }
  }
}
```

---

Note: this should not be confused with a rather poorly named [`scripted upsert`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/docs-update.html#scripted_upsert) which'll run the script irregardless of whether the doc already exists or not. This option should be omitted (or set to `false`).

Comment: Glad it helped! Hey I'm writing an elasticsearch handbook were I discuss real-word, non-trivial use cases like the one you were solving. There is a chapter or two on efficient ingestion & ingest pipelines and I think it'd bring you value. I'm close to finishing it but [let me know](https://jozefsorocin.typeform.com/to/XeQRxdwV) what else you'd like to learn about and I'll let you know when the handbook is out!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How does it impact the performance?

Comment: No problem. It depends on too many variables. On the one hand, you'd be accessing `_source` which is "costly" -- performance wise; on the other hand it's a simple one-doc operation. So it should be fine. There's no other way to achieve what you're after without an `upsert`.