# Elasticsearch bulk operation: insert if not existing, otherwise update or add a nested element

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-bulk-api, elasticsearch-php

In elasticsearch `7.11.0` I have products as described.

```
{
  "_index" : "products",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "1234567890123",
  "_source" : {
    "ean" : "1234567890123",
    "title" : "Very nice product",
    "merchants" : [
      {
        "id" : 2,
        "name" : "example.com",
        "product_id" : "22561",
        "description" : "Description of the product",
        "price" : "4.25",
        "url" : "https://example.com/product",
        "imageUrl" : "https://example.com/images/product.jpg",
        "in_stock" : true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I've added this product with a bulk `index` operation. It will update it if it exists and create it if it doesn't.

I'm receiving products from multiple merchants. A product can exist in one or more merchants. That's why I have the nested element `merchants`.

What is want to do as a `bulk` operation is the following:

Import runs:

- Product doesn't exist: `Create a new product with a nested merchant`
- Product exists: `Check if the merchant exists. If not, create a new nested element, otherwise update the nested elements`

I can do it one by one but due to the number of products it's not very convenient. I'm using the `elasticsearch PHP package`.

Comment: Have a look at the `upsert` option of the Update API that [I elaborated on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65900654/8160318) a while ago.

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for helping, I will give it a try. Does it work with 10mil+ products?

Comment: Yes it does. But I'd first try it with a subset of the documents limited by a query of your choosing.

Comment: If you run it on 10M+ docs, make to make it [asynchronous](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/docs-update-by-query.html#docs-update-by-query-task-api).

Comment: Thanks @JoeSorocin i will give it a try!